# Merging two csv file based on header values in python

Tags: python, csv, merge

I have two csv files. the first row of each file is the header and the rest of the rows are the data.

first file:

```
a, b, c, d, e, z,
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
```

second file:

```
a, b, c, f, g,
7, 8, 9,10,11,
```

and I would like to have a merged csv as follow:

```
a, b, c, d, e, f, g, z,
1, 2, 3, 4, 5,  ,  , 6,
7, 8, 9,  ,  ,10,11,  ,
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader), [`csv.DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter):

```
import csv
import itertools

with open('1.csv') as f1, open('2.csv') as f2, open('new.csv', 'w') as f3:
    reader1 = csv.DictReader(f1, skipinitialspace=True)
    reader2 = csv.DictReader(f2, skipinitialspace=True)
    fieldnames = sorted(set(reader1.fieldnames) | set(reader2.fieldnames))
    # If want empty-name column to be placed at the end,
    #   uncomment following statement.
    # Otherwise it will be place at the beginning.
    #fieldnames.remove(''); fieldnames.append('')

    writer = csv.DictWriter(f3, fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(itertools.chain(reader1, reader2))
```

If you're using Python 3.x, open files with `newline=''`.

Comment: Great! thank you falsetru. I want to use a .csv file which only has the headers as the header templates and the rest of the files should merge into it. How can i use it without sorting it? the dictWriter gives me errors when writing... I also wrote a function that walk the directory and sub directories where all my files are to be merged. Should  I open the merged file as f1 to merge again into it and have a temp as f3 which I overwrite at the end of each file onto the f1? Cheers

Comment: @cyrusR, Please post a separate question.

Comment: I will post another one, I didn't downnvote it. I am not rated enough in stackoverflow to be able to rate yet so I don't know how it happened...